# Stata - Show grouped frequencies

Tags: grouping, stata, data-management

I have a dataset with nations, studies, and data collections. I'm wanting to create a frequency distribution where it shows the total number of studies conducted in each nation.

The problem I'm running into is that my data is organized by data collections.  Some studies have multiple data collection sites and measure different parts of a nation (we'll say 3 areas).  Therefore, one study can have multiple rows.  However, for the table I need, I essentially want it to group the studies together, and report with a yes or no (0 or 1) of whether that nation was included in the study. Essentially, I don't care how many places in a nation were observed in each individual study. I just want to know whether or not a nation is included in a study. The example below may help.

Current data:

| Study | Data Coll | Nation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Brazil |
| 1 | 2 | Brazil |
| 1 | 3 | Brazil |
| 1 | 4 | France |
| 2 | 5 | Brazil |
| 2 | 6 | India |
| 3 | 7 | Brazil |
| 4 | 8 | France |

Desired Table:

| Nation | f (of studies) |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | 3 |
| France | 2 |
| India | 1 |

As you can see, in the top example, Study #1 observed 3 different areas of Brazil.  This nation was also observed in Studies #2 and #3.  The table I need to create just has a "3" by Brazil, as that is how many studies Brazil was included in.

Answer (score 1):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(study data_coll) str6 nation
1 1 "Brazil"
1 2 "Brazil"
1 3 "Brazil"
1 4 "France"
2 5 "Brazil"
2 6 "India" 
3 7 "Brazil"
4 8 "France"
end

contract study nation
drop _freq study
contract nation
list
```

Result:

```
. list

     +----------------+
     | nation   _freq |
     |----------------|
  1. | Brazil       3 |
  2. | France       2 |
  3. |  India       1 |
     +----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you wish to keep the original data structure, you can avoid using `contract`.

```
egen tag = tag(Nation)
egen wanted = total(tag), by(Study)
tabdisp Nation, c(wanted)
```